# Cannot `focus` after `blur` from another element in angular2

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, angular

Consider the following [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/drhfXAoI78mdeqlv3jYu?p=preview)

I have an input that will expand into dropdown when `(focus)` I want to have the following behavior

1. **When input is focused, user click anywhere that is not 
          in the `dropdown` or `input` , `dropdown` should be contracted**
2. **When input is focused, user click on the `dropdown`, `dropdown` should stay expanded**

Right now when user click on the input and click on the dropdown, the dropdown is contracted.

Here is my code for reference

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <div class="wrapper">
        <input [(ngModel)]="searchText" 
               tabindex="0"
               placeholder="name" 
               (focus)="inputShow()"
               (blur)="inputHide()" 
               >
        <div class="option-wrapper" 
             [hidden]="isHideList()" 
             tabindex="0" 
             (focus)="inputShow()" 
             (blur)="inputHide()">
          <li class="options" 
              *ngFor="#option of optionlist">
            <div >{{option['name']}}</div>
          </li>
        </div>
      </div>
    `
})
export class App {

    optionlist = [{'name': '1'}, {'name': '2'}]

    inputShow() {
      this.inputFocus = true;
    }
    inputHide(){
      this.inputFocus= false;
    }

    isHideList() {
        return !this.inputFocus;
    }
}
```

One way to get close to the expected behavior is to take away

```
(blur)="inputHide()"
```

on `input` like [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/wOzMrWT5zE0HoKCvY7sA?p=preview)

But now when I click on `input` and click anywhere besides `input` and `dropdown` the `dropdown` does not contract

Only if I click on `input` then `dropdown` then anywhere else does the `dropdown` contract

Can anyone give me some insight on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/1k2avULTifrRccAp165F?p=preview)

Listen to window click events and only hide the dropdown when the `event.target` is outside the wrapper:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <div #wrapper class="wrapper">
        <input #input [(ngModel)]="searchText" 
               tabindex="0"
               placeholder="name" 
               (focus)="inputShow()"
               > 
        <div class="option-wrapper" 
             [hidden]="isHideList()" 
             tabindex="0" 
             (focus)="inputShow()" 
             > 
          <li class="options" 
              *ngFor="#option of optionlist">
            <div >{{option['name']}}</div>
          </li>
        </div>
      </div>
    `
})
export class App {
    @ViewChild('wrapper') wrapper:ElementRef;
    @ViewChild('input') input:ElementRef;


    @HostListener('window:click', ['$event'])
    clickHandler(event) {

      var parent = event.target;
      while(parent != this.wrapper.nativeElement && parent != document) {
        parent = parent.parentNode;
      }
      if(parent == document) {
        this.inputHide();
      }
    }

    optionlist = [{'name': '1'}, {'name': '2'}]

    inputShow() {
      this.inputFocus = true;
    }
    inputHide(){
      this.inputFocus= false;
    }

    isHideList() {
        return !this.inputFocus;
    }
}
```